# Кастомная сортировка в MySQL

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Есть текстовое поле, по которому данные сортируются. В поле могут быть следующие символы:

```
-0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ЁАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяё
```

Сортировка в БД меня не устраивает: я хотел бы, чтобы порядок сортировки был таким:

```
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя
AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz
0123456789
```

При этом важно, чтобы Е и Ё рассматривались как один и тот же символ, а дефис - не учитывался.

Как подобное можно организовать в MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by replace(myfield,'ё','е')
```

Очень небыстро, но оно-таки отсортирует.
Хотите быстрее - копайте настройки кодировки или создавайте еще один столбец со строкой, в которой е и ё уже были заменены на е.

Comment: Передумав несколько вариантов решил остановиться на этом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Копать стоит в сторону collation. Где посмотреть порядок символов в каждой из них - не знаю. И не уверен, что удастся "Е и Ё рассматривались как один и тот же символ, а дефис - не учитывался."

Update: хотя нет, вот есть просмотр таблиц http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_unicode_ci.european.html. А с дефисами можно расправиться как-то так

```
SELECT REPLACE(columnname, "-", "") as c FROM T ORDER BY c
```